# How to convert .csv with WKB to shapefile (.shp) using open source solutions?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, convert, well-known-binary

I have a .csv file with hundreds of rows pulled out via PostGIS.

The geospatial information is in "the_geom" field which seems to be in WKB-format.

How can I convert this to shapefile using simple free tools?

Comment: did u try QGIS...?

Comment: Any chance of a sample for download?

Comment: I'm slightly worried about WKB in a CSV file, because CSV should be text, and WKB is Binary, so could have stray commas and quotemarks and zero-characters and line-ends that could mess up any text-parser. However if its WKT, the Text format, in your data then its trivial.

Comment: @Spacedman makes a good point. OP, can you copy/paste a couple rows of the csv data into your question? Make sure to click the [`edit`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/195176/edit) link below your question rather than adding them as a comment :)

Answer (score 5):

You can skip the CSV step and just go straight to shapefile using **pgsql2shp**, which is installed a part of PostGIS.

You could also use ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 2):

As a free on-line solution for the conversion of CSV with WKB data you can use [MyGeodata Converter](http://mygeodata.cloud/converter). Just name your column with WKB data as "wkb" - like this example:

```
id,name,wkb
1,Point 1,010100000000000000000048400000000000003340
2,Point 2,010100000000000000000046400000000000002E40
```

The WKB data will be automatically recognized based on the occurence of "wkb" string in a CSV column. Any geometry type is supported - point, linestring, polygon, ... If you have WKT, use name "wkt" of the column...
Hope it helps - for me it works.
It is based on [GDAL/OGR VRT driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html). Most of GIS/CAD formats are supported - both input and output data.

Comment: That's a hexadecimal string representation of WKB. I reckon that's probably what the OP has, rather than raw WKB bytes.